# how to define a tunnel connection to remote desktop in putty?

Tags: ssh, remote-desktop, putty, rdp, tunnel

I need to connect (in rdp ) to a machine (let's call it #1) in my college network ( I have the internal IP of it ) , I also have access the to Linux server machine in the same network in ssh , that I can use to access the #1 , 
I'm using putty, can someone please explain to me how I can connect to it ?

[My laptop] --->[Linux server] --->[windows machine] in rdp

Thank you,

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Let's assume the following:

Linux Server - `gate.college-server.com:22` (SSH listens on port 22)

Internal Server - `internal.college-server.com:3389` (RDP listens on port 3389)

RDP connection will be on `localhost:3399` (the port should be opened)

How to configure the SSH tunnel via Putty with RDP forwarding:

- Open Putty and in the `Session` enter the connection info for the Linux Server
- Go to branch > Connection > SSH > Tunnels
- Choose `Local` and `Auto`
- in the `Source Port` enter `3399`, and in the `Destination` - the connection info of the internal machine in the format: `hostname:port`.
- Click Add

you will see entry in the `Forwarded ports` section, something like:

```
4L3399   internal.college-server.com:3389
```

Save your connection and it's ready to use.

Next, start the a `PuTTy Session` with the Saved Connection and *after* you login *successfully*
to the remote server `gate.college-server.com:22`, you can start your Windows RDP client.

Connect with it to localhost:3399 and use the RDP credentials for `internal.college-server.com:3389`

Comment: in rdp client in windows, are sure  I have to enter: localhost:3399 ? it gives me an error "This computer can't connect to the remote computer"

Comment: and the forward ports look like this:
L3399   internal.college-server.com:3389
without the 4 in start , I did everything you mentioned

Comment: did you started the PuTTY session and logged in via SSH, before you tried the RDP client?

Comment: yes the 4 in the start indicates IPv4 is used, but than I thought it's better to use "Auto", but I forgot to adjust the example.

Comment: Crucial was the last sentence. internal.college-server.com:3389. This `:3389`